# Contain Scroll in a non-scrollable div

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I was working on a web page, which has a sidebar that opens as an overlay over the main content. The sidebar might or might not be scrollable (decided on the base of it's content height).
When the sidebar content overflows (making the sidebar scrollable on y-axis), I am able to contain the scroll behaviour within the sidebar by applying `overscroll-behaviour-y: contain`.

But when the sidebar is not scrollable, this class does not work, and scrolling inside the sidebar, scrolls the main content behind it. Is there any way to stop this?

Here's a codepen:
https://codepen.io/bilaljaved15/pen/jOeRQbE

In this codepen, the sidebar does not contain enough content to make it scrollable, and when we scroll inside the sidebar, the main content behind it gets scrolled, is there any possible way to avoid the scrolling of main content?

I tried `overscroll-behaviour-y: contain` and I also tried adding an onScroll action on the sidebar  as follows:

```
<div
    onScroll={(e)=> e.stopPropagation()}
>
...
</div>
```

None of this worked as the the onScroll action is not triggered when the sidebar is not scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem correctly, but you set a "position:fixed". Each position (only exception "position:static") raises the element by one layer, to prevent this create a parent container around the child elements and set a display:flex on it.

```
    <div style="display:flex">
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="p-4">
    <h1 class="sticky mb-10 text-4xl font-bold">This is is the sidebar </h1>
    <p>z
    This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar  This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar  This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar  This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar This is is the sidebar
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="w-screen bg-slate-700">
  This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content This is the main content 
</div>
  </div>
```

and remove the position in css:

```
.sidebar {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;

}
```